# How to insert value into BYTES column

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, byte, google-cloud-spanner

I have a `BYTES(16)` column and I'm trying to figure out how to insert a value, for example:

```
INSERT INTO
  Tenants (Id)
VALUES
  (b'GOlZkzqZRUas1VRmFAZOAw==')
```

> Query failed: New value exceeds the maximum size limit for this column in this database: Tenants.Id, size: 24, limit: 16.

What would be the proper way to do this insert? It seems it's reading it as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `b'GOlZkzqZRUas1VRmFAZOAw=='` literal will be interpreted as a raw byte string instead of as a `base64` string. To insert a `BYTES` value using a base64 string, you can use the `FROM_BASE64` function:

```sql
INSERT INTO
  Tenants (Id)
VALUES
  (FROM_BASE64('GOlZkzqZRUas1VRmFAZOAw=='))
```